# plot.new has not been called error when the plot() has been called

Tags: r

I'm trying to add points to a blank plot but am getting the plot.new error message.

Here is my code:

```
soy.nmds <- metaMDS(species.hell.soy, distance = "bray", k = 2)
```

```
plot(soy.nmds, type = "none", main = paste("NMDS/Bray - Stress=",
    round(soy.nmds$stress, 3)), xlab = c("NMDS1"), ylab = c("NMDS2"))
```

Which gives a plot:
[image: plot]

However, when I add points:

```
points(scores(soy.nmds, display = "sites", choices = c(1, 2)),
    pch = 21, col = "black", bg = "steelblue", cex = 1.2)
```

I am getting the error:

```
Error in plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) : 
plot.new has not been called yet
```

Is this an error in my rstudio settings or version?

I have tried with several other functions such as the abline and it still does not work even when the plot has clearly been called.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is (hopefully a reproducible example that still does not work on my computer):

```
dput(BOD) # use the built-in BOD data set.
```

```
BOD <- structure(list(Time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7), demand = c(8.3, 10.3,19, 16, 15.6, 19.8)), .Names = c("Time", "demand"), row.names = c(NA,-6L), class = "data.frame", reference ="A1.4, p. 270")
```

```
plot(BOD, aes(x=Time, y=demand))
```

```
abline()
```

```
error in int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...) : 
plot.new has not been called yet
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Hi @Quinten, i've added an example in the question above.

Comment: Your example is a bit messed up:  `aes()` is a `ggplot2` function, whereas `plot()` is from base graphics, and it will ignore `aes()`. I'd guess there's some interaction between the two systems that is causing your error.

Answer (score 0):

Try `dev.off` before your plot like this:

```
dev.off()
plot(BOD, aes(x=Time, y=demand))
abline(8,1)
```

Output:

[image]

For error `Error in dev.off() : cannot shut down device 1 (the null device).` try this:

```
while (!is.null(dev.list()))  dev.off()
```

Comment: Tried running dev.off(). Getting this error: Error in dev.off() : cannot shut down device 1 (the null device). 

I'm using Rstudio desktop, R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22). I've tried restarting but the problem persists.

Comment: Hi @Leahr-t, I added some code for your error in my answer!

Comment: Thanks for helping -  I'm no longer getting the dev.off error, but i'm still getting the plot.new has not been called error!

Comment: Try depending on your machine `window()` on windows, `quartz()` on mac and `x11()` on linux in your console and run your code again.

Comment: Tried quartz() - still coming up with the error unfortunately.